# Which of these two methods is the correct way to store data in vertex/edge?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the data we need to be able to:

- query comments by date
- see the text of the comments (stored in vertex or edge?)
- query data such as how many comments did the user contribute to an article (can be more than 1)

[image: Data model]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general vertex should represent entities and edges should represent relationships between entities. In your use case both graph models can fit the requirements. I personally prefer the first one. Considering you may need do more relations between a comment and other entities in the future, the first graph data model is more appropriated.

So you can do:

> query comments by date

```
MATCH (comment:Comment {date : '2017-05-01'})
RETURN comment
```

> see the text of the comments (stored in vertex or edge?)

```
// Since the comment is an entity you should store the text in the node 
MATCH (comment:Comment)
RETURN comment.text
```

> query data such as how many comments did the user contribute to an
>   article (can be more than 1)

```
MATCH (:User {id : 1})-[:MAKE]->(c:Comment)-[:ABOUT]->(:Article {id : 10})
RETURN count(c)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  Is there a speed or query difference between the two at scale?